# Add Static File Name and Extension to URL for PHP/JS Image Slideshow Script

Tags: javascript, php, static, append, filenames

We're trying to get an email signature plugin to 'randomly' load images from a cycling series of images.  It requires a standard HTML  tag, which requires a filename and extension for the 'src' (it doesn't download them with src=foo.com/ or src=foo.com/file.php).

I have a working PHP/JS image rotation script (below), but when uploaded as index.php the URL doesn't have the filename and extension of an image, so I can't trick the email signature plugin to download/embed the image.  **I'm looking to somehow append the static "/image.jpg" to the URL while rotating the images behind the scenes.**

```
<div id="sig"></div>
     <script>
       var myVar = setInterval(myTimer, 2000);
      var images = [];
      <?php

      // set $dir to your image directory
      $dir = "./images/";

// Open a directory, and read its contents
if (is_dir($dir)){
  if ($dh = opendir($dir)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
     if (!is_dir($file))
     {
      ?>
      //fill up the JS array with php values
      images.push("<?php echo  $file; ?>");
       <?php
       }
    }
    closedir($dh);
  }
}
?>
function myTimer() {
   var tt=Math.floor((Math.random() * images.length) + 1) - 1;
    document.getElementById("sig").innerHTML  = "<img src='./images/" + images[tt] + "'>";
}
     </script>
```

Tried mod-rewrite, but I'm not a coder and there's got to be a simpler way.